ASP.NET Core Web API : run mutiple projects from docker using variable
Please check the screenshot - I have two different Web API projects, Test1 and Test2:

I want to create one Docker image and run one of these two projects, based on the value of a variable.
I mean like if I want to run Test1 project, then I can pass in Docker command Test1 and it should run that project.
In the same way, if I want to run Test2 project, then it should run that project.
Is there a way to achieve this?
Thanks
